# What is the difference between gradlew assemble and gradlew compile

Tags: android, gradle

I noticed that

```
./gradlew tasks
```

for my android project gives me `assemble*` and `compile*` tasks.

What is the difference?

I also noticed that the command lists the tasks `compileDemoDebugSources` as well as `compileDemoReleaseSources` (where `demo` is a flavor and `release` is a build type) but only `assembleDemo` (instead of `assembleDemoDebug` and `assembleDemoRelease`) -- however the latter two work just as fine. Why is that?

Comment: Compile is language level (eg compile .java to .class). Your IDE may use this one for example. Assemble is for creating artifacts (eg WAR or JAR) from the various components, classpaths, resource files, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the official manual:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃         Task        ┃         Description         ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃      compileJava    ┃  Compiles production Java   ┃
┃                     ┃  source files using javac   ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃       assemble      ┃  Assembles all the archives ┃
┃                     ┃      in the project         ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

To investigate further, read Gradle 4.0 documentation:

- [Table 47.3. Java plugin - lifecycle tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/java_plugin.html)
- [Table 47.1. Java plugin - tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/java_plugin.html)

P.S. [drkstr1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108965/drkstr1) has already mentioned main differences in the comment.